# Box counting dimension example

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

Can anyone give me a sequence of nested sets each countable,
$$
S_1\supset S_2\supset S_3 \supset ...
$$
such that the box counting dimensions $\dim_{B}(S_n)$ are strictly decreasing and $S_n\subset [0,1]$?

Comment: Do you already know how to construct a countable set of intermediate dimension?

Comment: Nope, no idea to be honest.

Comment: Ok I will give a few ideas because a complete answer would be too long.  First, see that you can make a countable set with Minkowski dimension $\log(2)/\log(B)$ for any number $B$ by considering the points which contain only $0$ and $B-1$ in the base-B expansion and for which the expansion terminates (so that the set is countable).  Second, one can scale and translate a sequence of such sets and form $S_i$ as the union of them.  So long as the sets remain separated the box dimension of the union is the maximum box dimension of the parts.

Comment: Nice, not quite sure about the last bit. If you take a countable collection of separated parts then the box counting dimension isn't the maximum of the box counting dimension (or the supremum) over all the parts?

Comment: I agree that there are especially problems with countable unions.  However, I believe that if you squeeze each set $A_k$ to fit into the interval $[2^{-k}, 2^{-k}+ 2^{-k-1}]$ (where $A_k$ is a countable set with dimension $\log(2)/\log(k)$ as described above), then the construction works.  Try covering $S_i$ with subintervals of size $\epsilon$.  All sets $A_k$ with $k>|\log\epsilon|$ will fit in one interval, and the dominant contribution to the covering will be from the set $A_i$.